# Expandable RecyclerView issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an recyclerview that onClick expands the item to show a description.

It works properly expanding and collapsing but when I scroll with an expanded item some of the new items shown are expanded...

For example I have a recycler view with 50 items. I expand the first item and scrolldown and each 10 items there is a expanded one.

```
public class NotificationsExpandAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationsExpandAdapter.NotificationsViewHolder> {

    private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
    private ArrayList<SchoolNotification> mNotifications;
    private HashMap<String, String> typeNotifications;

    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(SchoolNotification notification);
    }

    public NotificationsExpandAdapter(ArrayList<SchoolNotification> notifications, Resources resources) {
        mNotifications = notifications;
        typeNotifications = eventsType(resources);
    }

    public NotificationsExpandAdapter(ArrayList<SchoolNotification> notifications, Resources resources, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        mNotifications = notifications;
        mOnClickListener = listener;
        typeNotifications = eventsType(resources);
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.notification_list_item_expand;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        NotificationsViewHolder viewHolder = new NotificationsViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mNotificationDate.setText(formatDateDayMonth(mNotifications.get(position).getDate()));
        holder.mNotificationType.setText(typeNotifications.get(mNotifications.get(position).getType()));
        holder.mNotificationTitle.setText(mNotifications.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.mNotificationDescription.setText(mNotifications.get(position).getDescription());
        if (mNotifications.get(position).getSubject().getName() != null) {
            holder.mNotificationSubject.setText(mNotifications.get(position).getSubject().getName());
        }
    }

    public SchoolNotification getItem(Integer position){
        return mNotifications.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotifications.size();
    }


    class NotificationsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements OnClickListener {

        TextView listItemNumberView;
        TextView mNotificationDate;
        TextView mNotificationType;
        TextView mNotificationSubject;
        TextView mNotificationTitle;
        TextView mNotificationDescription;


        public NotificationsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mNotificationDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_date);
            mNotificationType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_type);
            mNotificationSubject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_subject);
            mNotificationTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_tittle);
            mNotificationDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_description);
            mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        void bind(int listIndex) {
            listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(mNotificationDescription.isShown()){
                Utils.slide_up(v.getContext(), mNotificationDescription);
                mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Utils.slide_down(v.getContext(), mNotificationDescription);
            }


//            mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(mNotificationDescription.isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
//            if (mOnClickListener != null){
//                int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
//                mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(mNotifications.get(clickedPosition));
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no error in RecyclerView ... the only error is that you don't know what recycling means in RecyclerView ... basically you should store expand state for given item/id/position(not for view/viewholder
!) somewhere and apply it in onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewHolders are reused to increase performance of the list, so they remember their states. That's why some items appear expanded: they reuse ViewHolders, which were expanded earlier. To avoid the issue, you'd somehow remember which items were expanded (for example, save their positions in ArrayList) and perform a check in onBindViewHolder: if an item was expanded (such position is present in the ArryaList) - expand it, if it wasn't - collapse it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

Added a hashmap in the adapter class and id in holder class

```
public class NotificationsExpandAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationsExpandAdapter.NotificationsViewHolder> {

    private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
    private ArrayList<SchoolNotification> mNotifications;
    private HashMap<String, String> typeNotifications;
    private HashMap<Long, Boolean> expandedNotifications = new HashMap<>();

    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(SchoolNotification notification);
    }

    public NotificationsExpandAdapter(ArrayList<SchoolNotification> notifications, Resources resources) {
        mNotifications = notifications;
        typeNotifications = eventsType(resources);
    }

    public NotificationsExpandAdapter(ArrayList<SchoolNotification> notifications, Resources resources, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        mNotifications = notifications;
        mOnClickListener = listener;
        typeNotifications = eventsType(resources);
    }


    @Override
    public NotificationsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.notification_list_item_expand;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        NotificationsViewHolder viewHolder = new NotificationsViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.id = mNotifications.get(position).getId();
        holder.mNotificationDate.setText(formatDateDayMonth(mNotifications.get(position).getDate()));
        holder.mNotificationType.setText(typeNotifications.get(mNotifications.get(position).getType()));
        holder.mNotificationTitle.setText(mNotifications.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.mNotificationDescription.setText(mNotifications.get(position).getDescription());
        if (mNotifications.get(position).getSubject().getName() != null) {
            holder.mNotificationSubject.setText(mNotifications.get(position).getSubject().getName());
        }
        if (expandedNotifications.containsKey(holder.id))
            holder.mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            holder.mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public SchoolNotification getItem(Integer position){
        return mNotifications.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotifications.size();
    }


    class NotificationsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements OnClickListener {

        TextView listItemNumberView;
        TextView mNotificationDate;
        TextView mNotificationType;
        TextView mNotificationSubject;
        TextView mNotificationTitle;
        TextView mNotificationDescription;
        Long id;


        public NotificationsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mNotificationDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_date);
            mNotificationType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_type);
            mNotificationSubject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_subject);
            mNotificationTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_tittle);
            mNotificationDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notif_description);
            mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        void bind(int listIndex) {
            listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(mNotificationDescription.isShown()){
                Utils.slide_up(v.getContext(), mNotificationDescription);
                mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                expandedNotifications.remove(id);
            }
            else{
                mNotificationDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Utils.slide_down(v.getContext(), mNotificationDescription);
                expandedNotifications.put(id, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```